# Finding lattice points with fewest non-zero terms

Tags: complexity-theory, lattices

Finding a short point on a lattice is [hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Shortest_vector_problem_(SVP)), but I was wondering if finding a vector on the lattice which the fewest non-zero terms was easier?

Are there any good approximations like LLL, but which produce lattice points with lots of zeros?

Comment: The answer might depend on the dimension. If the dimension is small, you can try enumerating over the zero coordinates.